# How to add a JPanel in the center of another JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I Want to add a JPanel map on top of another JPanel WorldView in it's center just like this

[image: Example]

Here is my Code:

```
public class WorldView extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

private JPanel map;

public WorldView() throws IOException{
    this.setSize(1024,768);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    map = new JPanel();
    this.add(map);
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried to do to make it from what it is now, to what you want? What does it do now? Do you get any errors, or do you just not know where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `GridBagLayout` and modify the `GridBagConstraints#insets` or a `EmptyBorder` to generate the whitespace around the component in combination with `GridBagLayout` or some other layout like `BorderLayout` for example

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the constrctor :
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

Comment: Which is the default setting for a `JPanel` anyway